# return (n > 2) ? n = 5 : n = 4; doesn't work?

Tags: java, ternary

Why does this return an error

```
return (n > 2) ? n = 5 : n = 4;
```

but this does not

```
return (n > 2) ? n = 5 : n + 4;
```

Should it not be able to return `n` depending on either case?

Comment: return (n > 2) ? 5 : 4;

Comment: What language are you asking for? In what context is this line? And what's the error you're getting?

Comment: So ternary operators are used to return the value of the conditional statement variable only?

Comment: static int Func(int n)
    {

       return (n > 2)  ? 5 : 4;
    }

This is java syntax

Comment: update it in the question and also the error message, you got downvote for these

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you have can't be compiled because the ternary operator has a higher [`operator precedence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) than the assignment operator:

> **Operator Precedence**
>
> 1. postfix (`expr++ expr--`)
> 2. unary (`++expr --expr +expr -expr ~ !`)
>
> ...
>
> 13. ternary (`? :`)
> 14. assignment (`= += -= *= /= %= &= ^= |= <<= >>= >>>=`)

When parsing the code

```
(n > 2) ? n = 5 : n = 4;
```

it will parse it like this:

```
(n > 2) ? n = 5 : n     // ternary operator
                    = 4 // assignment operator
```

This would result in pseudo code like this:

```
someResultValue 
                = value;
```

That will not work and you get compile errors like:

> 'Syntax error on token "=", <= expected'

or

> 'Type mismatch: cannot
> convert from Object & Comparable<?> & Serializable to int'.

You can use parentheses to let java see the third argument of the ternary operator as `n = 4`. The code would look like this:

```
return (n > 2) ? n = 5 : (n = 4);
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have any syntax error. I tried that in chrome JS console and worked fine!!
[image: Solution of question]

**Update:** Some people argued in comments that I didn't write function so I wrote in functional format and got the same result![image]

Comment: Damn that's weird, it doesn't work in Java for some reason

Comment: It isn't a return of a function, this answer lacks the main concept

Answer (score 0):

syntax :
condition ? expression1 : expression2;

Try this

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       int a = 10;
       int b = (a>5)?a=5:0;
       System.out.println("a = "+ a);
       System.out.println("b = "+b);
       
    }
}
```

output:
a = 5
b = 5